# C# array only repeating first array item into excel fields

Tags: c#, excel

Only the first array item is being loaded into the cells, they're all getting the same value rather than each value being sent to its own cell

I have the same code being used in a save function that instead uses this code:

```cs
var iRowCount = xlSaveWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

var newRow = iRowCount + 1;
var timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
var rangeStart = string.Concat("A", newRow.ToString());
var rangeEnd = string.Concat("F", newRow.ToString());


string[] stringSaveArray = new string[] { textBox_Name.Text, textBox_Number.Text, textBox_Client.Text, textBox_Site.Text, richTextBox_Description.Text, timeStamp.ToString() };
Excel.Range rng = xlSaveApp.get_Range(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
rng.Value = stringSaveArray;
```

This option is working beautifully, so I'm confused as to why it works here and not in the other function

```
private void button_CopyTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fullTempPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\temp.xlsx";
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlTempWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullTempPath);
    Excel._Worksheet xlTempWorksheet = xlTempWorkbook.Sheets[1];

    string[] stringArray = new string[] { textBox_Name.Text, textBox_Number.Text, textBox_Client.Text, textBox_Site.Text, richTextBox_Description.Text };
    Excel.Range rng = xlApp.get_Range("B1","B5");
    rng.Value = stringArray;

    xlTempWorksheet.Range["A1:B5"].Copy();


    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlTempWorksheet);

    //close and release
    xlTempWorkbook.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlTempWorkbook);

    //quit and release
    xlApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
}
```

The values of the first array item are being put into every cell in the range, rather than each item going into the cell walking through the list

Comment: The first range is horizontal, and the second one is vertical. Try  `rng.Value = xlApp.Transpose(stringArray);`

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  It never even occurred to me that the problem was because the range in this case is vertical rather than horizontal.

Comment: Yep it's not exactly intuitive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-cell ranges accept and return two dimensional rectangular arrays. For example (not tested) :

```
xlWorksheet.Range["A1:B1"].Value = new[,] { {1, 2} };    // for "horizontal" range

xlWorksheet.Range["A1:A2"].Value = new[,] { {1}, {2} };    // for "vertical" range

xlWorksheet.Range["A1:B2"].Value = new[,] { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
```

Single dimensional arrays are accepted for horizontal ranges, but not for vertical.

As mentioned by @TimWilliams in the comments, `Application.Transpose` or [`Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) can be used to convert single dimensional array to two-dimensional "vertical" array :

```
xlWorksheet.Range["A1:A2"].Value = xlApp.Transpose(new[] { 1, 2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `rng.Value = stringArray;` use `rng.Value2 = stringArray;`

This will work.